# How do you connect a button to an array in RxSwift?

Tags: rx-swift

So I'd like to do something really simple with RxSwift as a proof of concept:

1. Crate an observable array;
2. When button is clicked add an integer to the array;
3. When the array has > 10 items empty the array.

This is mind numbingly impossible in RxSwift if you're a noob.

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with your outputs first, then work out how your inputs modify your output.

In your case, you haven't specified an output, so that may be part of why you are having such a hard time.

So let's start by having a number print to the console every time the button is clicked:

```
    let numbers = button.rx.tap.map { Int(arc4random()) }

    numbers.subscribe(onNext: { contents in
        print(contents)
    }).addDisposableTo(bag)
```

Run the above before going to the next step so you know what's going on.

Now let's accumulate them into an array:

```
    let numbers = button.rx.tap.map { Int(arc4random()) }
        .scan([Int](), accumulator: { (array, number) in
            array + [number]
        })

    numbers.subscribe(onNext: { contents in
        print(contents)
    }).addDisposableTo(bag)
```

Now let's add a guard to make sure the array stays < 10 elements...

```
    let numbers = button.rx.tap.map { Int(arc4random()) }
        .scan([Int](), accumulator: { (array, number) in
            guard array.count < 10 else { return [] }
            return array + [number]
        })

    numbers.subscribe(onNext: { contents in
        print(contents)
    }).addDisposableTo(bag)
```

Hope this helps!